# Do I need to sanitize user-inputted data, before sending it in an email

Tags: php, security, email

I have a form in which I accept name, email and message from a user. I do the validation for name, email and message and just send it using the `mail()` function.

If I was inputting the `$name`, `$email` and `$message` in a database, I would escape this data for SQL injection; or, if I was echoing it out on a webpage, I would use `htmlspecialchars()`.

What should I do when I am sending this data in a email? I know I don't have to worry about SQL injection, but what about XSS? Should I use `htmlspecialchars()` on these three variables too?

I send the mail like this:

```
mail('admin@mywebsite.com', 'Contact From: '. $name, "$message", 'From: '. $email);
```

I have read about email injection, but I can't understand it.

Please let me know about this.

Comment: It depends how you're using it. If you're setting the From header based on use input, then yes, it will need sanitizing.

Comment: This is also something that I don't understand! I look forward to seeing the answer for this.

Comment: mail('admin@mywebsite.com', 'Contact From: '. $name, "$message", 'From: '. $email);

Comment: "I would escape this data for SQL injection;" - I hope you would just use prepared statements instead :-/.

Comment: If you're sending it as plaintext message, there's virtually nothing that can go wrong in the *body*. If you're using any sort transport encoding or special format like HTML, you need to worry.

Comment: @user2471133 - in that case, if I include a linebreak in my email address, the next part of the input will be added directly into the headers of the email. So I can add extra recipients, for a start.

Comment: But I am using filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ,  although I don't use filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) on it because I don't understand it very well

Comment: @sleske: Prepared statements are not better than escaped dynamic SQL when it comes to security. In fact, some queries cannot be made with prepared statements.

Comment: Why are you talking about SQL injection and prepared statements here? we are not inserting anything in a SQL database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The escaping entirely depends on the context the data is embedded into.

Are you sending HTML mails? Then you have HTML context, and `htmlspecialchars()` must be used.

If you are sending plain text mails, there is no escaping for plain text.

The only threat would be that your mail client has some bug that interprets the plain text as something executable and then acts up when you get some strange names and mail adresses.

But this only applies to the mail's content, not the actual headers.

You are using a custom mail header `From`. Do not use this. `From` is used in spam filters. If I would enter my mail address, and you are sending this mail with `From: my@mail`, you are impersonating my own email server. Spam used to use this to hide the real source, and to redirect complaints and error feedback to the unhappy guy behind that mail address. Because of this today there are mechanisms that will prevent such abuse. So just do not pretend I am sending this mail - YOU do.

If you want to be able to answer me with a click on the reply button, use the `Reply-to` header, but always use `From: dont-answer@YOURWEBSITE.example`.

Additionally, these custom headers are the entry point for bad things. Make sure you are only adding mail addresses. Make sure you do not add any line feed characters. These would make the mailserver think that there is a new header coming up, and this might lead to mail header injection.

Comment: I am letting the user input everything, except where the email goes. So the user can enter html tags, script tags and such in the name, email and message field

Comment: I can't agree with "If you are sending plain text mails, there is no escaping for plain text."  Mischief can be done by spammers who send your form input that contains clever sequences of characters. If there is a good function to "sanitize" such input that goes into mail headers and body, making sure your program only works as you intended but not garbling valid input, I can't find it on the Web after much searching.

Comment: @DavidSpector The statement is true, whether or not you agree to it. The interesting part would be whether an attacker would be able to interfere with the processing of said plain text, i.e. trick some software into believing that it is NOT plain text, no matter what the mime type says. And of course, the issue remains with adding non-printable characters even though the text is handled correctly as plain text - this can likely mess up the output.

Answer (score 3):

you need to validate the email address to make sure it singular and not multiple addresses to stop email spamming

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

```
$email = "email@me.com";

 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "email not valid"; //  do not send
   }
 else
   {
   echo "email valid"; // send
   }
```

Comment: So I only need to validate the $email field, and not $name and $message?

Comment: @user2471133 email var is the main part but you could also change @ in name and message to [at]. `$name = str_replace( '[at]','@', $name);`  `$message = str_replace( '[at]','@', $message);`

Comment: some extra info for you [link]http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection[link]

Comment: Email messages are terminated by a skipped line then a period on a line by itself. This is a simple sequence of characters that anyone could input into your message body. So, if you are sending your own email directly you have to delete such a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple. If some user can send someone else a email he could use HTML or JavaScript wich is interpreted in most Email-Clients and every webmail interface to rewrite the contents. He could insert a iFrame loading another site or injecting a PopUp Script.

Its most important to sanitize the input the way you would sanitize it for a Browser.

Comment: HTML is only interpreted if the email headers state that the content contains HTML. Try sending a plaintext message containing <b>Hi</b> to someone...

Comment: You don't think I would damage the user's email like that? If I use htmlspecialchars() on it?

Comment: Even in plain text mails the attacker can simply insert a link to a malicious target and every modern client will highlight these... Sanitizing and filtering is important!